# trigonometric integral related centroid

Tags: calculus

Calculating the centroid of a part of rosacea $r(t) = 2a\cos(2t)$, did this definite integral. 
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos^3(2t)\cos t dt
$$
$$
\cos^3(2t)\cos t = \cos t\cos(2t)\cos^2(2t) = \cos t\cos(2t)\ \frac{[1 + \cos(4t)]}{2} = ??
$$
I tried to use the technique of double bow, but could not. Can someone help me?

Comment: Let $u = \cos t$ and then use one of the identities to represent $\cos(2t)$ in terms of $\sin t$.

Answer (score 5):

We know: $\cos(2t) = 1-2\sin^2t$. Let $u = \sin t$, we have:
$$I = \int_0^{\sqrt{2}/2}(1-2u^2)^3du$$
Then expand and integrate using power rule.